# Using v-html in blade foreach loop [Vue warn]: Error compiling template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use vues `v-html` in a blade foreach loop:

```
@foreach($entries as $entry)
    <a href="/entry/{{$entry->id}}"><h3>{{ $entry->created_at->toRfc822String() }}</h3></a>
    <div v-html="<p>hello world</p>">

    </div>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

When I do that I get this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>
> invalid expression: Unexpected token '<' in
>
> ```
> <p>hello world</p>
> ```
>
> Raw expression: v-html="
>
> hello world
>
> "

The reason I want to use `v-html` is because I intend to use a method to output markdown like `<div v-html="marked({{$entry-content}})">`

Comment: The raw html should be quoted as well `<div v-html="'<p>hello world</p>'"></div>`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule That works, but how would I get `<div v-html="marked({{$entry->content}})">` to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `marked` to be a method declared in Vue instance, you can quote the interpolated content but first convert all the characters in it to corresponding HTML entities. For example,

```
<div v-html="marked('{{ htmlentities($entry->content) }}')">
```

I suggest to write this in the model as a computed property.

```php
class Entry extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['content_html']

    getContentHtmlAttribute() {
        return htmlentities($this->content);
    }
}
```

Then use the computed field in your template,

```
<div v-html="marked('{{ $entry->content_html }}')">
```